# Duplicate AssemblyVersion Attribute

Tags: c#, compiler-errors

I have a project that generates following error on compilation:

> error CS0579: Duplicate 'AssemblyVersion' attribute

I have checked the file `AssemblyInfo.cs` and it looks like there is no duplication there.

I found [this article on MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pl-PL/vsgatk/thread/8671bdff-9b16-4b49-ba9e-227cc4df31b2) which addresses a similar problem and following the suggestion in this article fixes the problem as well.

Can anyone tell me what's going on here? Does it happen only in case of having two or more projects with classes having similar names? Or is it something else?

Comment: just a guess but, did you try close and that opening the solution again? perhaps that might solve it?

Comment: If converting a  project to .NET Core , see https://elanderson.net/2017/06/duplicate-system-reflection-assemblycompanyattribute-attribute/

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2017 Community edition on the Mac.  I had a console app and then I added a reference to a new class library project.  These errors started showing up when I did a build.  All I did was remove the reference to the class library project and then add it back and the errors went away.

Answer (score 200, accepted):

I have also run into this issue in the past, so I am going to assume that your build process provides assembly information separately to providing versioning. And that causes a duplication as your project also has that info in the `AssemblyInfo.cs` file. So remove the file and I think it should work.

Comment: So, Shouldn't build process overwrite the existing AssemblyVersion instead of creating a new entry? I know that our build process does that but I am curious that why it doesn't overwrite the existing one. Is it badly implemented or is it a limitation?

Comment: I think for .net assemblys the better way would be to use version injection method. But thats a seperate story. In your case the problem is there are different ways of providing assembly versions, through cmdline build parameters and through AssemblyInfo.cs and you have to make sure that only one method is being used as duplication of attributes is a .net compilation error.

Comment: remove what exactly?

Comment: Removing the AssemblyInfo.cs file fixed my issue.

Comment: I voted for this answer as it lead me to the best solution. The answer by "Serge Semenov" is also correct. One can selectively suppress the generation of the duplicities by <GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo> based on the the situation. In my case it was the debug profile.

Answer (score 382):

Starting from **Visual Studio 2017** another solution to keep using the `AssemblyInfo.cs` file is to turn off automatic assembly info generation like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

I personally find it very useful for projects which need to support both .NET Framework and .NET Standard.

Comment: Yes that worked for me, deleting the obj and bin folders wasn't enough.

Comment: Unfortunately, every time I change the `.csproj` file using its property pages (Application, Build, Build Events, etc.), the `PropertyGroup` with the `GenerateAssemblyInfo` disappears :-(

Comment: Move it into a Directory.Build.props file

Comment: Is there any risk or negative outcome possible with this solution?

Comment: @PaloMraz It seems that provided you're using a modern "SDK-style" csproj file, that modern versions of Visual Studio 2019 (e.g. 16.9.x) will preserve manual changes in the csproj file.

Comment: YES! Thanks. I wanted to USE the `AssemblyInfo.cs` attributes, not the auto-generated ones.  This answer allows me to do that.

Comment: So why is this not the default? What is GenerateAssemblyInfo required for? What did I just break by setting it to false?

Comment: I dont know why but it works! THANKS!

Answer (score 49):

In my case, there where a subfolder in a project that was a project folder it self:

- file system:

  - c:\projects\webapi\wepapi.csproj
  - c:\projects\webapi\tests\wepapitests.csproj
- solution

  - webapi (folder and project)

    - tests (folder)
- tests (folder and project)

Then i had to remove the subfolder "tests" from the "webapi" project.

EDIT 2022: Just to be more clear, as @bobt mentioned in the commentaries, by "remove" I meant: to right click the "tests" folder inside webapi and choose the option "exclude from project".

Comment: I had removed the subproject from the solution, but the subdirectory and files were still sitting there. Removing them finally fixed the problem.

Comment: Right click on the folder in Solution Explorer and choose "Exclude from Project". This way you don't have to restructure your folders.

Comment: You are right, @bobt, that is what I meant. I edited the answer to make it clear, thanks!

Comment: you can also set test project path in .sln file like  (..\test......)

Answer (score 23):

When converting an older project to .NET Core, most of the information that was in the AssemblyInfo.cs can now be set on the project itself. Open the project properties and select the Package tab to see the new settings.

The [Eric L. Anderson's post 
"Duplicate ‘System.Reflection.AssemblyCompanyAttribute’ attribute"](https://elanderson.net/2017/06/duplicate-system-reflection-assemblycompanyattribute-attribute/)  describes 3 options :

- remove the conflicting items from the AssemblyInfo.cs file,
- completely delete the file or
- disable GenerateAssemblyInfo (as suggested in [another answer by Serge Semenov](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10311347/duplicate-assemblyversion-attribute/44502724#44502724))

Comment: I find it more intuitive and more "Visual Studio" to specify these attributes in the project (`.csproj`), because they are metadata instead of code that describe actual logic. I hope in future everything can be specified in the project! (Currently I cannot specify COM visibility, so I leave it in `AssemblyInfo.cs`.)

Answer (score 22):

I had the same error and it was underlining the Assembly Version and Assembly File Version so reading Luqi answer I just added them as comments and the error was solved

```
// AssemblyVersion is the CLR version. Change this only when making breaking    changes
//[assembly: AssemblyVersion("3.1.*")]
// AssemblyFileVersion should ideally be changed with each build, and should help identify the origin of a build
//[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("3.1.0.0")]
```

Comment: I tried this, and it changed nothing in my case :-(

Answer (score 21):

There must be already a AssemblyInfo.cs file in the project here:
[image]

To solve:
- Delete any one AssemblyInfo.cs

Answer (score 14):

I came across the same when tried add GitVersion tool to update my version in AssemblyInfo.cs. Use VS2017 and .NET Core project. So I just mixed both worlds. My AssemblyInfo.cs contains only version info that was generated by GitVersion tool, my csproj contains remaingin things. Please note I don't use `<GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>` I use attributes related to version only (see below). More details here [AssemblyInfo properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/csproj#assemblyinfo-properties).

**AssemblyInfo.cs**

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("0.2.1.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("0.2.1.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyInformationalVersion("0.2.1+13.Branch.master.Sha.119c35af0f529e92e0f75a5e6d8373912d457818")]
```

**my.csproj** contains all related to other assembly attributes:

```
<PropertyGroup>
   ...
  <Company>SOME Company </Company>
  <Authors>Some Authors</Authors>
  <Product>SOME Product</Product>
   ...
  <GenerateAssemblyVersionAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyVersionAttribute>
  <GenerateAssemblyFileVersionAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyFileVersionAttribute>
  <GenerateAssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute>
</PropertyGroup>
```

[image: csproj maps to package tab at project properties]

Answer (score 11):

In my case, some temporary *.cs files generated during compilation got accidentally added to the project.

The files were from the `obj\Debug` directory, so they definitely shouldn't have been added to the solution. A `*.cs` wildcard went a little crazy and added them incorrectly.

Deleting these files fixed the problem.

Answer (score 6):

My error occurred because, somehow, there was an obj folder created inside my controllers folder. Just do a search in your application for a line inside your Assemblyinfo.cs. There may be a duplicate somewhere.

Comment: Similarly, I had a .csproj file (A) inside another folder belonging to another .csproj (B).

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this recently with no changes to source, but after experimenting with some new project references. I got into a state where this error was appearing even after reverting all changes in the branch.

Cleaning the branch resolved it for me:

`git clean -xfd`

Answer (score 4):

For me it was that AssembyInfo.cs and SolutionInfo.cs had different values. So check these files as well. I just removed the version from one of them.

Answer (score 4):

When you create a *project*, Visual Studio sets it up to compile & generate a corresponding *assembly*.  Each project generates 1 assembly, and so each has a corresponding *assembly configuration* to generate its assembly from.

The problem is when you **create *more than one project*** that ***each can generate their own assembly***, and then ***include one of these projects in the other***.

In this scenario, Visual Studio gets confused and doesn't know which config file to go off of to generate *the single assembly for the project* -- it finds the second assembly configuration in the *included* project and says "HEY, DUPLICATE! You've given me two sets of instructions for generating my assembly!"

But sometimes you still want the *included* project to be able to generate an  assembly on it's own, ***but*** not when it is being included in another project.

To obtain this, one solution is to add conditional defines to the *including* project (found in *project Properties*).  Then change the assembly config in the *included* project to look for this conditional define.  If it is defined (by the *including* project), then the config can skip over it's content -- this will result in only 1 config found by VS -- the one from the *including* project -- problem solved!

#### Steps Below (screenshots included)

Step 1: Select the *including/container* Project > Right Click > Properties

[Project properties (screenshot)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VNEwxXS2KoVKK1QGjoApSADZxuj5O7by/view?usp=sharing)

Step 2: Navigate to Build > General > Conditional compilation symbols

*Add your conditional defines as shown:*

[Conditional compilation symbols (screenshot)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XbKSV_nbLwpN8d9I0H4-fPlQYecnKcJF/view?usp=sharing)

Step 3: Use conditional defines in the *included* project AssemblyInfo.cs

[Using conditional defines (screenshot)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Eyh9IRAOKceALHuR6C_MRBFOWnwxv_nO/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: This all sounds right but I'm having a hard time finding settings in the project properties in VS2022. I've looked at the csproj as well but I'm not sure where or what lines to add to conditionally or unconditionally remove the assembly from the encompassing solution

Comment: I added the steps with screenshots in my OP.  This should make it easier to find your way around :)

Comment: The screenshots helped

Answer (score 2):

Yet another solution when upgrading core to VS2017 is to remove them in the properties\assemblyinfo.cs file.

Since they now are stored in the project.

Answer (score 2):

This usually happens for me if I compiled the project in Visual Studio 2017 & then I try to rebuild & run it with .NET Core with the command line command "dotnet run".

Simply deleting all the "bin" & "obj" folders - both inside "ClientApp" & directly in the project folder - allowed the .NET Core command "dotnet run" to rebuild & run successfully.

Answer (score 2):

You can remove **bin** and **obj** file and clear the cache of the project. My issue was fixed from that.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, one of my colleagues had removed a Console App used for testing purposes, that was placed in the same directory as our Api, and then committed to Git.
When I later pulled from Git, the console app itself was ofcourse gone, but it's bin and obj folders was still there, resulting in the AssemblyInfo.cs file being present in both the root application dir and the subdir for the old console app. Simply removing the bin and obj folders for the old console app resolved the issue.

ASP.NET Core 3.1

Answer (score 1):

I found this answer on msdn, that explains marking the file as Content and then Copy to Output = If Newer. See article below:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8671bdff-9b16-4b49-ba9e-227cc4df31b2/compile-error-cs0579-duplicate-assemblyversion-attribute?forum=vsgatk

GH

Answer (score 1):

Edit you AssemblyInfo.cs and #if !NETCOREAPP3_0  ... #endif

```
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
// General Information about an assembly is controlled through the following
// set of attributes. Change these attribute values to modify the information
// associated with an assembly.

#if !NETCOREAPP3_0  

[assembly: AssemblyTitle(".Net Core Testing")]
[assembly: AssemblyDescription(".Net Core")]
[assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCompany("")]
[assembly: AssemblyProduct(".Net Core")]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright ©")]
[assembly: AssemblyTrademark("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCulture("")]

// Setting ComVisible to false makes the types in this assembly not visible
// to COM components.  If you need to access a type in this assembly from
// COM, set the ComVisible attribute to true on that type.
[assembly: ComVisible(false)]

// The following GUID is for the ID of the typelib if this project is exposed to COM
[assembly: Guid("000b119c-2445-4977-8604-d7a736003d34")]

// Version information for an assembly consists of the following four values:
//
//      Major Version
//      Minor Version
//      Build Number
//      Revision
//
// You can specify all the values or you can default the Build and Revision Numbers
// by using the '*' as shown below:
// [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]

#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this error when I did put 2 projects in the same directory. If I have a directory with an solution and I put a separate Web and Data directory in it compiles right.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue when my main project was in the same folder as the solution, then I had a separate project in the same solution located in a sub folder, and that separate project used the main project as a reference. This caused the main project to detect the sub folder bin & obj folders which created duplicate references.

Comment: This helped me out a lot!
One project referenced another as a build-time dependency, but a bug in the csproj caused the obj folders to be different, generating this error.

Answer (score 1):

If you're having this problem in a Build Pipeline on Azure DevOps, try putting the Build Action as "Content" and Copy to Output Directory equal to "Copy if newer" in the AssembyInfo.cs file properties.

Answer (score 1):

I got the error Just after switching from .NET Framework to .NET Core.  I have 2 class library projects in my Visual Studio solution.  I realized that 1 of the projects has a file named `AssemblyInfo.cs` while the other project does not have the file.  The file is located under the `Properties` folder. I simply delete the Properties folder and all works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I have being struggling with this issue, but my problem was much easier to solve.

I had copied OBJ folder to "OBJ___" name to do some compilation tests.

So, I don't know why, this folder was being also compiled, creating the assembly attributes duplication.

I simply deleted the "OBJ___" folder and could compile successfuly.

Answer (score 1):

I got these errors because I tried to temporarily rename the obj folder to obj_, and then it's included in the project automatically. Then the assembly.cs in it began to fight with the right one in obj folder generated later.

Answer (score 1):

In my case i had a single Git/azure project.
Inside the solution there were multiple small related projects C# (and even some angular)

Exit visual studio, for each project edit the .csprj file.

find the `<PropertyGroup>` tag and in there add the line  **`<GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>`**

so it might look eventually like, (there's probably more in it, in your case)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="Current" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ActiveDebugProfile>https</ActiveDebugProfile>
    <GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

There is no need to re-organize or delete folders, or to put it in separate gits etc.

Answer (score 0):

My error was that I was also referencing another file in my project, which was also containing a value for the attribute "AssemblyVersion". I removed that attribute from one of the file and it is now working properly.

The key is to make sure that this value is not declared more than once in any file in your project.

Answer (score 0):

```
obj\Debug\netstandard2.0\PacktLibrary.AssemblyInfo.cs(15,12): error CS0579: Duplicate 'System.Reflection.AssemblyConfigurationAttribute' attribute [c:\Users\John_Tosh1\Documents\C#8.0and.NetCore3.0\Code\Chapter05\PacktLibrary\PacktLibrary.csproj]
obj\Debug\netstandard2.0\PacktLibrary.AssemblyInfo.cs(16,12): error CS0579: Duplicate 'System.Reflection.AssemblyFileVersionAttribute' attribute [c:\Users\John_Tosh1\Documents\C#8.0and.NetCore3.0\Code\Chapter05\PacktLibrary\PacktLibrary.csproj]
obj\Debug\netstandard2.0\PacktLibrary.AssemblyInfo.cs(17,12): error CS0579: Duplicate 'System.Reflection.AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute' attribute [c:\Users\John_Tosh1\Documents\C#8.0and.NetCore3.0\Code\Chapter05\PacktLibrary\PacktLibrary.csproj]
obj\Debug\netstandard2.0\PacktLibrary.AssemblyInfo.cs(18,12): error CS0579: Duplicate 'System.Reflection.AssemblyProductAttribute' attribute [c:\Users\John_Tosh1\Documents\C#8.0and.NetCore3.0\Code\Chapter05\PacktLibrary\PacktLibrary.csproj]
obj\Debug\netstandard2.0\PacktLibrary.AssemblyInfo.cs(19,12): error CS0579: Duplicate 'System.Reflection.AssemblyTitleAttribute' attribute [c:\Users\John_Tosh1\Documents\C#8.0and.NetCore3.0\Code\Chapter05\PacktLibrary\PacktLibrary.csproj]
obj\Debug\netstandard2.0\PacktLibrary.AssemblyInfo.cs(20,12): error CS0579: Duplicate 'System.Reflection.AssemblyVersionAttribute' attribute [c:\Users\John_Tosh1\Documents\C#8.0and.NetCore3.0\Code\Chapter05\PacktLibrary\PacktLibrary.csproj]
```

I believe my Library folder was corrupted by an inadvertent creation of another class library.I deleted the library an all associated file but the problem persisted.  I found a workaround by deleting ALL bin and obj folders in the directory. The build was ok previously but found a subfolder that had the same assemblyinfo.cs file.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is a reference conflict which is mostly peculiar to VS 2017.

I solved this same error by simply commenting out lines 7 -14 as well as Assembly version codes at the bottom of the page on AssemblyInfo.cs

It removed all the duplicate references and the project was able to build again.

Answer (score 0):

I just helped a team member resolve this issue by renaming the repo folder the re-cloning the repo. This was only an issue for one developer as everyone else on the team was able to build *master* without hitting this error so we knew the problem wasn't an issue in source.

We did try deleting bin and obj folders and doing a `git clean -xfd` but neither of those resolved the issue. Starting fresh with a clean copy of the repo did the trick in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I've being struggling with this issue too.
In my case ,I had put solution and project in a same place .So I had problem .After I chose a folder for solution and put the project in this solution ,it worked properly.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I changed my folder structure and tried to push. Git told me I had to pull first and I did. That duplicated my source code in the old folder **and** the new one, so lots of duplication errors came up at build time.

Simply removing the duplicated folders resolves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error in my project on the .NET Framework solved the problem by deleting in the project folder packages/GitVersion*

Answer (score 0):

I'm using AWS CDK to create a lambda function from a separate project inside the same solution.

For me **DockerImageCode.FromImageAsset** copied over code, Dockerfile and build files (obj and bin folders). You don't need the obj and bin folder when you just want the code and Dockerfile.

What I did to resolve the issue was to exclude the **obj** an **bin** folders like this:

```
var customerServiceApiCode = DockerImageCode.FromImageAsset("../CustomerServiceApi", new AssetImageCodeProps
{
  Exclude = new []
  {
    "/bin",
    "/obj"
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Encountered this error in the project recently converted to Azure Function, where the local directories "bin" and "obj" were not removed. Deleting these folders locally resolved the issue.