# SonarQube says critical bug : provide an 'AssemblyVersion' attribute for this assembly 36 times

Tags: c#, .net, sonarqube, assemblyversionattribute

I am using SonarQube for the first time and a scan of my project revealed 38 bugs. 
36 are the same bug:

> Provide an 'AssemblyVersion' attribute for this assembly.

SonarQube says to resolve this bug I need to add

```
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("MyAssembly")]
[assembly: AssemblyVersionAttribute("1.2.125.0")]
```

before the namespace in each of the 36 files...

However, when I add it to even one file (With the correct title and version number) I get these errors in Visual Studio:

[image]

I read this [questions and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10311347/duplicate-assemblyversion-attribute) and am more confused than before. 
I read [this article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/328977/The-Right-Way-to-Version-Your-Assemblies) about "The right way to version your assemblies" and moved my projects' `AssemblyInfo.cs` into a linked `VersionInfo.cs` file like the article suggested.

At this point I am at a loss, how do I fix these 36 bugs? What is the best practice for providing Assembly Version?

Comment: What are the versions of your SonarQube and SonarC# plugin?

Comment: How do you analyze your project? Using the latest scanner for msbuild and msbuild 14 I cannot reproduce the issue. Same for msbuild 12 and 15.

Comment: @hellyale is the VersionInfo.cs placed in a shared project? http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/7ca517/shared-project-an-impressive-features-of-visual-studio-201/

Comment: @hellyale I still cannot reproduce the problem. I created a simple solution with several projects (https://github.com/valhristov/multiple-assembly-version-bug). Can you try it and let me know if I am missing something? Since we cannot detect where you want to put your shared assembly attributes, we raise once for each project...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was using the `DEPRECIATED` `sonar-scanner.bat` to analyze my files.

I followed the directions to set up [SoanarQube scanner with MSBuild](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+MSBuild) as Amaury Leve pointed out and once I was building with MSBuild 15 the `AssemblyVersion` bugs all disappeared from the analysis results.

Answer (score 1):

The rule is checking the assembly-level attributes that are already compiled and you should be able to follow the pattern with a linked AssemblyInfo.cs.

I think you are experiencing a bug with the issue reporting on our side, we have [an open ticket](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-csharp/issues/225) about it and we are aiming at providing a fix at the end of the next week. If that's the case, you should be seeing much less reported errors with [SonarLint for Visual Studio](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SonarSource.SonarLintforVisualStudio).

Comment: Thanks, so safe to ignore these for now