# Build failed but no errors in the error list?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I've tried building my project but its having none of it, no errors displayed in the error window and I've already tried everything that the other questions have suggested.

What have I tried?

- Rebuilding Solution
- Restarting Visual Studio
- Restarting Computer
- Deleting `bin` folder

Any output? Yes, but unfortinatly its too long to send here. 
https://pastebin.com/raw/53f47F0C

Comment: Did you try clean your solution?

Comment: Hi

I can see the following error in your output: "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\workspace\projects\Seegal\Seegal Client\Seegal Client\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs(14,12,14,29): error CS0579: Duplicate 'AssemblyTrademark' attribute" 


So maybe have a look here: [Duplicate AssemblyVersion Attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10311347/duplicate-assemblyversion-attribute)

Comment: There are no duplicated attributes in my AssemblyInfo.

Comment: There clearly is a duplicate. The compiler does not lie to you.

Comment: Attributes don't necessarily need to be in the `AssemblyInfo.cs` file, they could be anywhere in the project. Also, Visual Studio 2017 (with the new `.csproj` format) automatically generates attributes if you don't explicitly tell it not to, so if you have them in `AssemblyInfo.cs` they are duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

On your pastebin link appears two errors:

1>  C:\Users\admin\Desktop\workspace\projects\Seegal\Seegal Client\Seegal Client\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs(14,12,14,29): error CS0579: Duplicate 'AssemblyTrademark' attribute
1>  C:\Users\admin\Desktop\workspace\projects\Seegal\Seegal Client\Seegal Client\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs(15,12,15,27): error CS0579: Duplicate 'AssemblyCulture' attribute

Watch carefully AssemblyInfo.cs file, there must be two duplicated attributes.

Comment: There are no duplicated attributes in my AssemblyInfo.

Comment: Try to remove them, there must be a build process that provides them. Perhaps on build project properties...