# Error CS0579 occurs on TFS build agent but succeeds when build is run locally

Tags: c#, .net-core, tfsbuild

I am getting CS0579 errors from my TFS automated build system.  The same build script works fine on my development machine.  Build is also successful in Visual Studio.  The project is that is erroring is C# netcoreapp3.1 and platform x64

ERROR:
Tests.AssemblyInfo.cs(15,12): error CS0579:
Duplicate 'System.Reflection.AssemblyFileVersionAttribute' attribute

Error is repeated for several other attributes:

1. System.Reflection.AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute
2. System.Reflection.AssemblyProductAttribute
3. System.Reflection.AssemblyTitleAttribute
4. System.Reflection.AssemblyVersionAttribute

Am I missing something on my build agent?  What could be going on?

Edit:
I should have mentioned that there is no AssemblyInfo.cs in the project and that
false property is already set in the csproj.

Also, as mentioned above the build script has been run successfully on my workstation.  Subsequently it has also been run successfully on another dev workstation.  But, fails consistently on the TFS build agent.

Comment: Can this discussion help you?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10311347/duplicate-assemblyversion-attribute

Basically removing AssemblyInfo.cs file can help it seems.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Duplicate AssemblyVersion Attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10311347/duplicate-assemblyversion-attribute)

Comment: What's the result if you modify the csproj and add this property `<GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>`? Also, try deleting the AssemblyInfo.cs file if your project contains it.

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT we already have that property set in the csproj

Comment: @KorayElbek already do not have an AssemblyInfo.cs  Sorry should have mentioned that

Comment: Have you tried to run, manually, in the machine that has the build agent. Go to the build agent's work folder, and try to run each of the steps. Verify that the source folder is how you imagine it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `error CS0579: Duplicate 'System.Reflection.xxx' attribute` always indicates that there're extra AssenvlyVersion available in your build process.

1.So you need to check if you pass MSbuild arguments like `/p:Version /p:AssemblyVersion` as build arguments.

2.Make sure you're using `Dotnet build task` to build the project.

3.Double check to make sure you don't have any `xx.AssemblyInfo.cs` in project directory.

4.Make sure the `bin/obj` folder are not checked in source control. Then delete the `agent_work` folder or `_work` folder of your build agent to make a clear working directory. Choose `Clean=true` for your `Get Source` step.

[image]

[image]