# "Duplicate assemblies encountered" error while publishing a MAUI application

Tags: android, maui

I have no problems debugging my MAUI app on my Android device but when i try to publish it i get an error. I am using Visual Studio Community 2022 17.5.1. Here's the bad portion of output:

```
Duplicate 32-bit hash 0x2159891885 encountered for assembly Microsoft.Maui
Duplicate 32-bit hash 0x2159891885 encountered for assembly Microsoft.Maui
Duplicate 32-bit hash 0x2159891885 encountered for assembly Microsoft.Maui
Duplicate 32-bit hash 0x3800979733 encountered for assembly Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility
Duplicate 32-bit hash 0x3800979733 encountered for assembly Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility
Duplicate 32-bit hash 0x3800979733 encountered for assembly Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility
Duplicate 32-bit hash 0x2758225723 encountered for assembly Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml
Duplicate 32-bit hash 0x2758225723 encountered for assembly Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml
Duplicate 32-bit hash 0x2758225723 encountered for assembly Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml
Duplicate 32-bit hash 0x2480646305 encountered for assembly Microsoft.Maui.Controls
Duplicate 32-bit hash 0x2480646305 encountered for assembly Microsoft.Maui.Controls
Duplicate 32-bit hash 0x2480646305 encountered for assembly Microsoft.Maui.Controls
Duplicate 32-bit hash 0x2861189240 encountered for assembly Microsoft.Maui.Essentials
Duplicate 32-bit hash 0x2861189240 encountered for assembly Microsoft.Maui.Essentials
Duplicate 32-bit hash 0x2861189240 encountered for assembly Microsoft.Maui.Essentials
XABLD7009: System.InvalidOperationException: Duplicate assemblies encountered
```

Please help, have no idea what to do.
PS: in my project i use Plugin.Maui.Audio and Community Toolkit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following steps:

1.try to delete the `obj` folders and `bin` folders of every platform, then rebuild it

2.if your build process provides `assembly` information separately which may cause a duplication as your project also has that info in the `AssemblyInfo.cs` file. So try to remove file `AssemblyInfo.cs`.

and you can try to use the `AssemblyInfo.cs` file is to turn off automatic assembly info generation like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

And there is a similar thread here, you can refer to [Duplicate AssemblyVersion Attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10311347/duplicate-assemblyversion-attribute?page=1&tab=modifieddesc#tab-top).